# How to add soundButton(on&off) on a activity in android apps?

Tags: android, button, audio, android-activity

I Have created a branch activity .Now i wanted to add two button on that branch activity.
When i click on 'sound on' button then my beep sound on start and when i clicked on 'sound off' then my beep sound off. and also they hide simultaneously.

Thank's

**MY Code on Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sound_layout);





    soundBttnOn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.soundBttnOn);
    soundBttnOn.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startMediaPlayer();
                }
            }
        );

    soundBttnoff =(Button) findViewById(R.id.soundBttnOff);
    soundBttnoff.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener(){ 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stopMediaPlayer();
                }
            }
        );
    }

     private void startMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SoundLayout.this,R.raw.keybutton5);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void stopMediaPlayer() {
        if( mediaPlayer != null ) {
            MediaPlayer mp = null;
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    }
```

It showing no problem but it is not working too..:P..I am not able to implement sound.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: yes, i have create two button on on xml file. and trying to add on it on my activity.but m stuck .and Don't know to proceed. because i wanted to off phone sound with that button so .i don't have any sound to add on raw file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simple google search to find tons of samples for adding button. However for playing sound file check out the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class.

```
Button startBtn, stopBtn;
//get the reference of Button
....

final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
startBtn.onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+audio.mp3);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};  

stopBtn.onClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {      
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    //hide buttons
                    stopBtn.setVisibiltiy(View.GONE);
                    startBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }   
     }
};
```

PS: For only on and off, you don't need two buttons, you could do with one button.

**EDIT:**

For single button, just use the playing state of Media player for deciding about the action to take on button click.

```
singleBtn.onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            if(mp.isPlaying()) mp.stop();
            else {
                mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+audio.mp3);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok I am going through your suggestion.I wanted to add a single button .so when i click on that single button**sound on** with the msg(sound on) as well  when i click on the same button ** sound Off** with the msg(sound off). but m not able to implement it as well..:(